# How do I use the /particle command in Vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The command instructions say

```
/particle <name> <x> <y> <z> <xd> <yd> <zd> <speed> [count] [mode]
```

but how do I use those? I understand the `<x>`, `<y>` and `<z>`, but first of all, what are `<xd>`, `<yd>`, and `<zd>`? Also, what does the speed do, and how much does any given number change it? What do count and mode do?

I basically just want to know what all the positional and optional arguments in the `/particle` command do, and how I can effectively use them.

Comment: I believe that the xyz-d co-ords specify the are around which the particles will spawn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/particle <name> <x> <y> <z> <xd> <yd> <zd> <speed> [count = 1] [mode = normal]`

I'll explain all arguments:

- `name`: Which particle you want to spawn. [Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Particles)'s a list.
- `x y z`: Coordinates of the particle you want to spawn. (Enter `~` for current position, add a number after the `~` for an offset. Example: `~3` = current position target dimension + 3)
- `xd yd zd`: Is the area radius you want to spawn the particle in. You can see it as a square: `/particle ... 0 0 0 5 5 5 ...` spawns somewhere randomly between `-5, -5, -5` and `5, 5, 5`. Leave 0 for exact position.
- `speed`: Specifies the speed in a random direction of the particle. Leave 0 for stationary.
- `count`(optional): How many particles you want to spawn, or in other words: how many times the command should be executed.
- `mode`(optional): `normal` or `force`. This specifies if the everyone should be forced to see the particle. People with the option `particles` on `minimum` can't see particles that are more then 16 blocks away, but with `force` specified it forces the client to display the particle so they can see it no matter what distance.

Example:
`/particle explode ~ ~ ~ 5 5 5 0.1 100` will generate 100 smoke
particles around the player within a radius of 5 at a slightly increased speed of `0.1`.

More info [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#particle)

Comment: I don't understand the speed modifier, every time I use it the particle doesn't appear.

Comment: @Spyfiend13 ... or doesn't _seem_ to appear! If you have it too high, it may fly so fast that's almost unnoticeable. Maybe check other arguments too.

Comment: I tried putting it at 0.1 for hugeexplosion and I didn't see it, maybe it's getting interference fro  another command. Also, one time I saw it appear really far away.

Comment: @Spyfiend13 Hmm... Put your code here?

Comment: Ok, it turns out it was thee count that was messing it up. I tried "/particle hugeexplosion 983 135 1059 974 134 1051 0.1 1 force", and that didn't work, then I tried "/particle hugeexplosion 983 135 1059 974 134 1051 0.1 0 force" and that did work. I also tried changing the speed, like "/particle hugeexplosion 983 135 1059 974 134 1051 1 0 force" or "/particle hugeexplosion 983 135 1059 974 134 1051 100 0 force" and the speed didn't change.

Comment: @Spyfriend You messed up `xd yd zd`. Remember the particle will be spawned within a box with a xradius of xd, yradius of yd, zradius of zd with the center as x, y, z.
`/particle hugeexplosion 10 10 10 5 5 5 1 10` is a good command.

Comment: Ok, so for xd yd zd, 5 5 5 would spawn it in a random spot within 5 blocks in every direction from the starting point?

Comment: @Spyfiend13 affirmative.

Answer (score -4):

when you use particles (ex:/particle note ~ ~ ~ 10 10 10 10 10 10) i would first check on the internet but if you dont have internet *DUMB!*.first type"/particle"  then type the name of the particle (ex:note) then the place of the world you want it from "/particle note " then the xd the yd and the zd which is the dynamiter of the how big it is.last you have the three last slots you have the speed the count and the mode. i would sujest looking else where for that part! hope i helped!!!

Comment: AND also the in the xd yd zd means how **BIG** it is 'Ha'